# Why an array comparison of sorted array in both ascending and descending in a single block of code/function results to true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arrow-functions, challenge-response

**Why do ascending and descending arrays give the same output? Anyone can solve this?**

```
function isSortedAndHow(arr) {
  let asc = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b); // Ascending order , yes
  let dsc = arr.sort((a, b) => b - a); // descending array, yes

  if (arr == asc) {
    console.log("Ascending , Yes");
  } else if (arr == dsc) {
    console.log("Descending , Yes");
  } else {
    console.log("No");
  }
}
isSortedAndHow([25,20,15,30,35]);
```

Comment: another issue is that array is sorted in-place, so the initial array is changed as well
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Andy, they aren't different objects (which is the problem, `arr == asc` will always be true), `sort()` returns a reference to the original array (after sorting in place)